# ajax.post doesn't work on android device

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

ajax.post works great in the browser but doesn't work on the real android device(and I don't know how I can see the error because I have left browser environment).
I think I have a problem with Internet permission or origin restriction. I have read about ManifestAndroid.xml but I can't find it in my project.(no such file)

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Here is my config.xml:

```html
 <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
```

Here is index.html restrictions:

```html
<access origin="http://example.com" />


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: 'unsafe-eval';
    style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    connect-src * ;
    script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
    media-src *">
```

Comment: The manifest file is inside of an android project. Since this is a website, it probably wont work without that permission. does this help you? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html

Comment: I need to add some confs so my app will require network access before app is built to apk. So where should i put these requirements? By the way , there is no android folder inside of pladform folder (just browser)

Comment: Do you have whitelist plugin installed?

Comment: I am not sure. I took a standard libs package and did not add anything

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my Angular 2 App, the things I did are follows:

1) When you load Android Studio, you can select `File->Profile APK` to debug/run you APK, then you can look at the logcat to see any error messages.

2) Add the [`allow-navigation` tag in `config.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#allow-navigation)
You need to add the [Whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to the [plugin section of the config](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#plugin)

3) What is the URL that you are making the request to? My big problem was that I was using relative URLs and because my Web App is on the device not the server, my relative path was pointing to file protocol file:// not http://.
So I would recommend making sure the URLs are absolute, ie http://, overwise your app could be doing a post to the file system not that's why it's failing

Comment: I use PhpStorm to develop an app. Any ideas ?

Comment: How are you making the post request? Are you using Angular or jQuery or something else? `console.log()` to see the URL you are posting to, does it start with `http://`?
Android Studio is used for running the APK in an emulator, I don't think PHPStorm can load up a APK - Try downloading Android Studio, you may need it if you plan on creating more apps